# Simpler way to build large $\omega$-models

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

Consider the following statement:

> $(*)\quad$ There are $\omega$-models of ZFC of arbitrarily large cardinality.

This is provable in ZFC + "There is an $\omega$-model of ZFC" alone. The proof I know is a "nuke:" just check that the Keisler-Morley theorem (Theorem $4.2$ [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02771605)) is provable in ZFC alone.

My question is:

> What's a simpler proof of this fact?

It looks to me like Keisler-Morley is doing much more work than should be necessary for this weaker result, but I don't immediately see a simpler argument.

Comment: This is a nice question. You cannot ensure the existence of transitive models of different heights just from knowing that there are transitive models. So you are near the boundary, in a sense. What is the softest way you know of enlarging an $\omega$-model (without increasing cardinality)?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I'm embarrassed to say I don't know of any! I'm pretty illiterate when it comes to nonstandard models of  set theory *or* arithmetic, really.

Comment: Something involving omitting types surely ensures the existence of $\omega$-models of size $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I'm probably having a silly moment, but I don't see it immediately since there are too many types nonstandard natural numbers could have to kill them all at once with the OTT. But maybe I'm not being clever enough?

Comment: @Andres: Suppose $M$ is the model, force to add a countably complete $M$-ultrafilter (e.g. extend the club filter of $\omega_1^M$), then take the generic power in $M[G]$, whose critical point is $\omega_1$. Iterate this embedding through the ordinals of $M$. What do you get?

Comment: @Asaf Yes, that would be the Woodin-Larson approach; I'll have to think about how bad things get as you iterate, though. I was hoping to avoid forcing, in the spirit of "simplicity".

Comment: The upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem gives elementary extensions of an arbitrary model of arbitrary size. The problem is that I'm not sure if it gives end-extensions.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson It does not give end-extensions in general, so it doesn't answer this question.